# How to serialize WCF message using DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

I am trying to serialize WCF message using DataContractSerializer to get the message size (without using service trace viewer). Following is the code snippet:

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            byte[] bytes = null;
            var messageBuffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            var message = messageBuffer.CreateMessage();
            var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Message));
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                dcs.WriteObject(ms, message);
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message size = {0}", bytes.Count()));
            }
        }
```

On doing so it raises the following exception:

> Type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage'
>   cannot be serialized. Cons ider
>   marking it with the
>   DataContractAttribute attribute, and
>   marking all of its  members you want
>   serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the
>   typ e is a collection, consider
>   marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.

What can be done?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Can you confirm you are not using v3.5 (not SP1)

Answer (score 1):

The Message class is not a data-contract type or an Xml Serializer type. WCF special cases it. To find the length, your code shoudl look more like this:

```
    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var messageBuffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        var message = messageBuffer.CreateMessage();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
            message.WriteMessage(xw);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message size = {0}", ms.Length));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `WriteMessage(XmlWriter)` on a `Message` instance in the Created state, if you need to serialize it.